How to save two separate CSVs when you are parallelizing your code?
I currently have this code running
def single_iteration(iter:int):
   some_parameters = 100
   data1, data2, data3, data4 = do_something()
   result = []
   for i in range(100):
       data = {'Col1':data1, 'Col2':data1, 'Col3':data3, 'Col4':data4}
       result.append(data)
   df = pd.DataFrame(result)
   return df

if __name__ == "__main__":
   run_stop = 100
   number_of_cores = int(os.environ['SLURM_CPUS_PER_TASK'])
   with multiprocessing.Pool(number_of_cores) as pool:
      results = pool.map(single_iteration, range(run_stop))
   df = pd.concat(results, ignore_index=True)
   df.to_csv(path, file_name)

However, now I want two different CSVs , like with df1 = pd.DaFrame[{'Col1':data1, 'Col2':data2}] and df2 = pd.DaFrame[{'Col3':data3, 'Col4':data4}] and return them in each run and then concat them separately and save them.

(Tangentially, code you put in if __name__ == '__main__': should be trivial; the purpose of this boilerplate is to allow you to import the code, which you will not want to do anyway if the logic you need is not available via import. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/69778466/874188)

import os
import multiprocessing
import pandas as pd


def single_iteration(iter: int):
    some_parameters = 100

    data1 = [1] * 100
    data2 = [2] * 100
    data3 = [3] * 100
    data4 = [4] * 100

    result1 = []
    result2 = []

    for i in range(100):
        data1_dict = {'Col1': data1[i], 'Col2': data2[i]}
        data2_dict = {'Col3': data3[i], 'Col4': data4[i]}
        result1.append(data1_dict)
        result2.append(data2_dict)

    df1 = pd.DataFrame(result1)
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(result2)
    return df1, df2


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_stop = 100
    number_of_cores = int(os.environ.get('SLURM_CPUS_PER_TASK', 4))

    with multiprocessing.Pool(number_of_cores) as pool:
        results = pool.map(single_iteration, range(run_stop))

    # Separate the results into two lists of DataFrames
    df1_list = [res[0] for res in results]
    df2_list = [res[1] for res in results]

    # Concatenate all DataFrames in each list
    df1 = pd.concat(df1_list, ignore_index=True)
    df2 = pd.concat(df2_list, ignore_index=True)

    df1.to_csv('df1_file_name.csv', index=False)
    df2.to_csv('df2_file_name.csv', index=False)

